# Titanium Appcelerator API call error - HTTP ERROR

Tags: ios, ember.js, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am having a website which contains login page. When user tries to log in using username and password. Data is being passed in Form Data. Please have a look as following image to get idea.

[image]

Now I want to use the same api in my Titanium application and get all details or logged in user which i am performing using below mentioned code.

```
var url= "http://www.randomwebsite.com/login/";
 var jsonData = {
    username: "admin",
    password: "password1"
 };
 var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
 xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    alert("DATA IS " + JSON.stringify(obj));
 };
 xhr.onerror = function(e) {
    Ti.API.info("ERROR " + e.error);
 };
 xhr.onsendstream = function(e){
    Ti.API.info("onsendstream");
 };
 xhr.ondatastream = function(e){
    Ti.API.info("ondatastream");
 };
 xhr.open('POST',url);
 xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

I am getting HTTP error. I even tried setting xhr.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json') as well as verified url its same as that is being used by website. Can any one help me out with this ? Or is there any way in order to make sure that titanium code passes data in form-data ? Or any suggestion regarding this would be of great help.

Comment: What error are you getting? What else is in the webpage http header? Sometimes webpages have security checks or other values to make sure that you just use the form on the page. Or you need to have a cookies set or something else.

Comment: Thanks for your response first of all. Actually error that I am receiving is HTTP error that is printed on my Titanium console. And this api is called on loading of webview. Just now as demo purpose in order to check whether all api that is being used on web site would be called from my mobile application or not.

Comment: Its working fine now. Mistake that I was doing is that i was stringifying text when data was being send. 
So changing `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsonData))` to `xhr.send(jsonData)` works for me. Hope so this would help some one.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine now. Mistake that I was doing is that i was stringifying text when data was being send. So changing `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsonData))` to `xhr.send(jsonData)` works for me. Hope so this would help some one.